# ¿Que Tablas usar para una Base de Datos que almacene Roles de Usuarios?

Tags: base-de-datos, aplicación-web

tengo que diseñar una base de datos que sea capaz de almacenar los datos de un usuario y su Rol en una pagina web, dichos roles son: Trabajador, Empleador y Administrador.

Lo que me confunde es como hacer esas relaciones. Principalmente hice unas relaciones entre:

```
--------------------------------------------------

| Trabajador | 0,1  ------  0,n --->>  | Rol  |


--------------------------------------------------
```

Asi mismo con la entidad empleador

```
--------------------------------------------------

|Empleador  | 0,1 ------- 0,n --->> |Rol|

--------------------------------------------------
```

La otra forma de hacerlo seria Asi:

```
| Usuario |-- 0,1--------- 0,n --->> |Rol|
```

Creando una Entidad Usuario se puede guardar los datos de los usuarios junto con una columna llamada rol_usuario donde esta el ID de la tabla o entidad Rol.

Mi pregunta es, si se hace de la segunda forma, ¿ como pueden los usuarios tener 2 roles?, ¿Deben tener dos cuentas diferentes para cada rol?

Ó ¿ Hay una forma mejor de hacer ese tipo de relación?

Espero haberme expicado. Agradecería caulquier ayuda, empujon o regaños. Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te comento el SGBD es indistinto para la tarea que deseas cumplir, por ponerte un ejemplo si yo deseara realizarlo en MySQL, sería del modo siguiente:

1. Creo una tabla de roles que me va a guardar la información de cada uno de los tipos de usuario que van a existir en mi sistema
2. Creo una tabla de usuarios a la cual por medio de un `FOREIGN KEY` vinculo con el id de la tabla de roles para poder identificarlos de manera única.
3. Cuando estes por dar de alta primero llena la tabla de roles, para que después en un combo box desde un formulario cuando un usuario se registre pueda elegir su tipo de usuario por ejemplo.

Te adjunto el SQL breve pero efectivo de mi explicación anterior

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rol_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    rol_status TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    status_user TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    rol_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_roles FOREIGN KEY(rol_id) REFERENCES roles(id)
);
```

Comment: Entendido a la perfección Alfredo Paz, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esta clase de preguntas, **siempre** (**pero siempre**) depende de las reglas de tu negocio.

No hay una sola forma de hacer esto, y las reglas son quienes definen el formato de las tablas.

En tu caso, decis que hay una tabla usuarios, una sola tabla de usuarios.

Y una tabla de roles, con un RolId, y supongo que una lista de permisos.

Y aca es donde importan las reglas de tu negocio.

Si se aceptan varios roles por usuario, vas a tener una tabla Usuario_Roles, que contendra ID_usuario y ID_rol y se relacionara con las otras dos n a n.

Si solo se acepta un rol por usuario, basta con que pongas el ID_rol en la tabla Usuarios.

Sin embargo, y vuelvo a insistir, este esquema no es fijo, ni siempre es asi. Podrias tener una tabla de caracteristicas, donde guarde el usuario y las caracteristicas del mismo, que incluye el rol (o los roles).

Comment: Excelente, buen aporte, gracias.

Comment: @OdannysDeLaCruz no es necesario agradecer. Lee por favor el [tour] del sitio asi sabes como funciona.

Comment: Rayos @gbianchi, sé como funciona esto, simplemente siento las ganas de dar GRACIAS, puedo? Te molesta? Tengo que romper con mis costumbres para complacer a una pagina?, si te molesta que te agradesca, pues no digas nada. GRACIAAAS

Comment: jajaja.. no, no hay problema.. pero que no se haga costumbre ;) de nada... @OdannysDeLaCruz